# How can I do a default scope in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

I previously used `default_scope :order => 'group_name'` because I wanted it for all uses.

This doesn't work in Rails 4

I tried

```
scope :default, -> { order('group_name')}
```

which didn't raise a syntax error, but also didn't work - groups are not ordered by name

I can add a scope but I'd like to know if there's a replacement for all as a default.

Comment: No syntax error was raised since what you tried correctly creates a scope named `default`. So now you can say, `MyActiveRecord.default` and you'll get your active record ordered by `group_name`. :)

Answer (score 2):

Should be declared as

```
default_scope {order('group_name')}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Don't do it!](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/806-default_scope-is-evil)

But if you have to:

`default_scope { order('group_name') }`

From: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-default_scope